# SocketException (0x274c) while accessing service with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dotnet-httpclient

I have a *httpClient* code piece in this piece of code I requested (PostAsync) 3 times to the service like;

```
private async Task<Data> SendRequestToTheService(string searchTerm)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

        Response response = new Response();

        await Step1(param1, client);

        await Step2(param1, param2, client);

        response = await Step3(param, client);
        return response;
    }
}
```

As you can see inside of the steps I send a request(*postAsync*) to the same service.

In my local everything is run clean. I got response successfully.

But when I deploy my codes to the server It works few times clean then return bellowing **server error**.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xx.xx.xxx:443

**StackTrace**

> [**SocketException (0x274c):** A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond xxx.xx.xx.xxx:443]
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +8439919    System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress&
>   address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Exception& exception) +315
>
> [**WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server**]
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +322
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +137
>
> [**HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.**]
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60    AAA.XXXX.Mvc.Controllers.d__14.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Projects\AAA.XXXX\src\AAA.XXXX.Mvc\Controllers\SearchController.cs:276
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   AAA.XXXX.Mvc.Controllers.d__11.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Projects\AAA.XXXX\src\AAA.XXXX.Mvc\Controllers\SearchController.cs:192
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>
> task) +60    AAA.XXXX.Mvc.Controllers.d__6.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Projects\AAA.XXXX\src\AAA.XXXX.Mvc\Controllers\SearchController.cs:87
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +92
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +385    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +38    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +38    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
>   +212    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +166

I checked many topics about socket error (0x274c) but I didn't find any useful solution for me. Probably on my server has a network related error but I didn't solve it.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new instance of `HttpClient` every time. Microsoft says to create a static instance, and [this](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) explains why.

Comment: I don't create a new instance of httpClient. I passed which I create in using. @john I am passing the same client. I edited the code

Comment: But thank you. I am going to try to create static httpClient now. I tried with static httpClient. the result is same first 2, 3 trying its working then it's not. same error

Comment: Yes, but each time you call `SendRequestToTheService` you're creating a new HttpClient, which creates a new thread pool, which isn't disposed of for some time after your code completes. It might not be your issue, but it might help.

Comment: with telnet, can you open that domain or ip address on port 443?

Comment: Socket programming requires retry mechanism and proactive processing such exceptions. You simply cannot assume there would be no exceptions on the wire. If you do want to know the exact cause, enable System.NET tracing and when the exception happens again the trace log would tell.

Comment: Lex Li, what should I track in the trace log. now I enabled to trace logs but when I examine but it doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The network guy added a load balancer to the server and if the application uses different pool IP's which is not whitelisted in service so we got this exception. Thanks for comments, time and helps.

Comment: Right, I did not have such problem on dev/staging environment(one web-server only), but once deployed to PROD balanced servers my site timeouted to call webapi. Admin folks had to set up proper accesses and it solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to know. this sharing helps!