# SocketException (0x274c) while accessing API via System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, server

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. There I consume an API service via `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. Here is the controller that performs the job

```
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        public HomeController()
        {
          _client = new HttpClient()
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(SearchParam searchParam)
        {
            // API Initialization
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Uri);
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // API Consumption By HttpClinet
            var url = _searchService.GetApiQueryParams(searchParam);
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);

            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response.Rootobject>(jsonString);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var searchResults = _searchService.GetSearchResults(rootobject, searchParam);
                return View("SearchResult", searchResults);
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Sorry some internal error occur !");
            return View("SearchResult");
        }
```

This works fine on my `Local Server` as well as on an `IIS Server`. But when I publish the application to a different hosting Server and try to consume the API it shows [this](https://prnt.sc/jpuk2q) error.

I have found two similar issue. Please have a look at these

- [SocketException (0x274c) while accessing service with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858830/socketexception-0x274c-while-accessing-service-with-httpclient)
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318140/prb-error-on-net-client-that-consumes-a-web-service-through-an-http-pr

From the first issue, I didn't get the "load balancer to the server".
And from the second issue when I add the solution in the `Web.config` it shows an error for `proxyaddress="http://proxyserver"` which make sense.

Now I am badly in need of a solution to this problem. I am not good at questing, so please feel free to suggest or correct any error.

Comment: Did you try to telnet the API server IP/Port from the place where you have hosted your app? It could be some firewall issues if you are not able to connect using telnet.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea about telnet in application level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, the problem solved. Mentioning the [second issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318140/prb-error-on-net-client-that-consumes-a-web-service-through-an-http-pr) I emailed the problem to the  Hosting provider, they provide a `system.net` `configuration`.  Using this `system.net` `configuration` in `Web.config` solved the issue.

```
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy>
  <proxy
    usesystemdefault = "false"
    bypassonlocal="false"
    proxyaddress="http://hosting-provided-proxyaddress-here"
  />
 </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```